# How to make make syntax highlighting and keyboard behavior identical for VB.NET and C# in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, syntax-highlighting

**C#**

- Types have their own color (cyan by default).
- Enter completes the auto-complete suggestion.

**Visual Basic**

- Types use Identifier color (black by default).
- Enter completes the auto-complete suggestion and adds a "()" and a newline.

These and other seemingly minor differences are so enraging I can't get any work done. How do I make Visual Studio behave consistently? Failing that, any other solutions/suggestions?

Edit: I don't care which way, I just want it to be consistent.

Comment: Enraging, eh? Have you considered raising a complaint on Microsoft Connect?

Comment: They only accept complaints about Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VB.NET and C# IDEs merely look the same.  They are actually very different chunks of code that don't have much in common beyond the text editor engine.  They did a pretty good job making them look similar, it certainly wasn't that way in earlier releases of VS.  But there are subtle differences here and there, like the ones you are fretting over.

You'll need to get over this.  Pick, say, global warming or the economy to direct your rage.  Or a hapless contributor to SO :)